# Rails 4 ActiveRecord Association with nested form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I read half all I could get my hands on and while there are sections of very clear explanations for what I am trying to do I cannot find an up-to-date complete tutorial. I have pages and categories. Pages has_many categories and categories has_many. I have also setup a 3rd model categories_pages and create an indexed join table with 2 columns in it (category_id & page_id). So my models are currently:

```
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :category
belongs_to :page
end


class CategoriesPages < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :category
belongs_to :page
end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base

#categories
has_many :categories_pages
has_many :categories, :through => :categories_pages
end
```

Then I have a form which is this (please ignore that there is missing paperclip code in the page model above.. i snipped it from this example but can confirm uploads files as it should).

```
    <%= form_for(@page) do |f| %>
  <% if @page.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@page.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this page from being saved                          </h2>

      <ul>
      <% @page.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :title %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :title, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :text %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :text, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= form_for @page, :url => pages_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |form| %>
        <%= form.file_field :image %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.fields_for :category do |cat| %>
        <%= cat.label :name, 'Category' %> </br>
        <%= cat.text_field :name %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :published %><br>
      <%= f.check_box :published, :class => 'checkbox' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :seo_keywords, 'SEO Keywords' %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :seo_keywords, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :seo_description, 'SEO Description' %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :seo_description, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="action">
      <%= f.submit 'Save', :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
    </div>
  </form>

<% end %>
```

My question is what do I put in the controller/s (assuming the above code checks out). I have not found up to date information on this. Railscasts is way out of date and the more I read (I have been trying to solve this since yesterday) the more I went around in circles. At the moment I have the form rendering in the edit or new view but the save button is completely unresponsive. I am not sure my controller code is correct (only my second week using rails) so I haven't posted it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit 1:

I forgot this crucial piece of information. The form renders fine no errors however the submit button is unresponsive (I click it and nothing happens). The form saves fine when the category field is removed.

Edit 2: Log info

```
Started GET "/pages/8/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-23 03:27:33 +0800
Processing by PagesController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"8"}
  [1m[36mPage Load (1.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `pages`.* FROM `pages`  WHERE `pages`.`id` = 8 LIMIT 1[0m
  Rendered pages/_form.html.erb (29.9ms)
  Rendered pages/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (31.7ms)
  [1m[35mUser Load (2.7ms)[0m  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
Completed 200 OK in 184ms (Views: 67.8ms | ActiveRecord: 88.1ms)


Started GET "/assets/categories.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-23 03:27:34 +0800


Started GET "/assets/menu.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-23 03:27:34 +0800


Started GET "/assets/adminpanel.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-23 03:27:34 +0800


Started GET "/assets/posts.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-23 03:27:34 +0800


Started GET "/assets/pages.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-23 03:27:34 +0800


Started GET "/assets/sessions.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-23 03:27:34 +0800


Started GET "/assets/scaffolds.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-23 03:27:34 +0800


Started GET "/assets/users.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-23 03:27:34 +0800


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.min.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-23 03:27:34 +0800


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-23 03:27:34 +0800


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-23 03:27:34 +0800


Started GET "/assets/categories.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-23 03:27:34 +0800


Started GET "/assets/posts.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-23 03:27:34 +0800


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-23 03:27:34 +0800


Started GET "/assets/sessions.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-23 03:27:34 +0800


Started GET "/assets/menu.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-23 03:27:34 +0800


Started GET "/assets/adminpanel.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-23 03:27:34 +0800


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-23 03:27:34 +0800


Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-23 03:27:34 +0800


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.min.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-23 03:27:34 +0800


Started GET "/assets/pages.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-23 03:27:34 +0800


Started GET "/assets/users.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-23 03:27:34 +0800
```

Edit 3: pages_controller

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_page, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /pages
  # GET /pages.json
  def index
      @pages = Page.all
  end

  # GET /pages/1
  # GET /pages/1.json
  def show
    @page = Page.new(page_params)
  end

  # GET /pages/new
  def new
    @category = Category.new
    @page = Page.new
  end

  # GET /pages/1/edit
  def edit

  end


  # POST /pages
  # POST /pages.json
  def create
    @page = Page.new(page_params)
    @category = @page.build_category(category_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @page.save
        format.html { redirect_to @page, notice: 'Page was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @page }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @page.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  # PATCH/PUT /pages/1
  # PATCH/PUT /pages/1.json
  def update
    @page = Page.new(page_params)
    @category = @page.category

    @category.assign_attributes(category_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @page.update_attributes(page_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @page, notice: 'Page was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @page }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @page.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /pages/1
  # DELETE /pages/1.json
  def destroy
    @page.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to pages_url, notice: 'Page was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_page
      @page = Page.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def page_params
      params.require(:page).permit(:title, :text, :image, :published, :seo_keywords, :seo_description)
    end

    def category_params
      params.require(:category).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

Comment: Did you got any error? Also please specify what's the exact problem is.

Comment: Sorry.. I updated the question. The problem is that the form submit button is completely unresponsive.

Comment: Are the values are saving correctly? Please post the log info.And also this line  `<%= f.fields_for :category do |cat| %>` should be  `<%= f.fields_for :categories do |cat| %>` if it is a `has_many` relation with the category.

Comment: Ok fixed the categories thing (it was left over from when I tried a one to one relationship instead). I have pasted the development.log from click edit on a page and then trying to update and save it. As you can see nothing happens when I click the f.submit

Comment: Done. I only posted the pages controller as I am assuming this is the only controller that is relevant?

Comment: Why you are having `form_for` inside an another `form_for` though both relates to `@page`?

Comment: To be honest I don't quite understand how the 'magic' of rails works yet. The update action in the category controller has to be set? What else? Also what about the join table? According to my research the join table will be automatically populated and doesn't need any controller?

Comment: Are you having the problem with `edit` only or with both `create` and `edit`?

Comment: Ok sorry no I was mistaken in my last comment. The second `form_for` is from paperclip and is necessary for uploading a file (image in this case) into the page table. This was working perfectly before I added the category field.

Comment: Problem is with both edit and create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `form_for` tag generates all necessary html for the `<form>` tag including action,method and so on. Have a look at the generated sources code to understand, what the 'magic' does. You see 'nothing happens' because your submit button is placed in another `<form>` block (outside the form_for block) which has no `action` attribute set. And - you see - no `action` leads to 'no action'.

**UPDATE**:

In order to correct the behavior join the forms like that:

```
<%= form_for @page, html: { role: 'form' } do |f| %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@page.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this page from being saved </h2>
    <ul>
      <% @page.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title, :class => 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :text, :class => 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  ...
  <div class="action">
    <%= f.submit 'Save', :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The second `form_for` is for the paperclip gem (according to their instructions). The image upload this facilitated was working perfectly before I introduced the category field.

Comment: but your `form_for` block does not contain anything except display of the error messages. I am referring to the `<form role="form">` block

Comment: Ok... this did not affect the functionality of my form submit at all though. `<form role="form"> is some markup for bootstrap.

Comment: My point is: *there is no submit button inside of the `form_for` block!*

Comment: Sorry if my last comment wasn't clear... Removing the `<form role="form">` had no effect so it is not what is causing my current issue.

Comment: But still.. you will not see anything happen until you add a submit button to the `form_for` block :) Maybe I have to make my point more clear: You may have multiple forms on a single html page. Every form must define its on submit button. clicking that button will only submit its parent form data to the url defined in the `action` attribute of the form. When a form has no `action` set, clicking the button will cause nothing to happen, just like a link with no `href` attribute

Comment: How do I go about doing what you suggest?

Comment: Ok it seems you are correct the 2nd `form_for` is breaking the submit button. This is very confusing as I had successfully uploaded images using the form with the second `form_for` and now it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me, I finally go it all to work. I am assuming that the first image uploads erroneously worked when they shouldn't have (maybe something to do with not restarting the server). I'm still confused as to why this could have even been possible but I feel I have learned a lot through the process. Thanks again